# VBA loop in change event error

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro that creates a textbox in worksheet 2 when I write something in cell A1 of worksheet 1, and when I delete that value it deletes the textbox.
I want to do that for several cells, but it just is working. If Cell A1 has a value a textbox with that value should appear, if the A2 has a value a textbox with that value should appear, but if I delete A1 it should delete the texbox that refers to A1, not all of the textboxes

```
Sub RemoveShapes()

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Worksheets(2).Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then shp.Delete
    Next shp

End Sub

Sub criarcaixastexto()

    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Dim box As Shape

    Set wsActive = Worksheets(2)
    Set box = wsActive.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 20, 20, 100, 50)

    box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("Folha1!A1").value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Call criarcaixastexto
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
'macro para apagar
Sub removercaixas()

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Worksheets(2).Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then shp.Delete
    Next shp

End Sub

'macro para criar caixas de texto
Sub criarcaixastexto()

   Dim wsActive As Worksheet
   Dim box As Shape

   Set wsActive = Worksheets(2)
   Set box = wsActive.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 20, 20, 100, 50)

   box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value

End Sub

' macro corre ao escrever texto numa célula
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    For i = 1 To 3
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A&i")) Is Nothing Then
            removercaixas
        If Len(Target) > 1 Then criarcaixastexto
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe exactly what the error is. "doesn't work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: removercaixas removes all textbox shapes.  you need to use shp.TopLeftCell.Address to determine the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing all textboxes on the sheet any time you call `removercaixas`. You need to somehow link the textbox with the cell it was generated by.

Why not name the textbox with the cell address? Copy/Paste this:

```
Sub removercaixas(strName As String)

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Worksheets(2).Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox AND shp.Name = strName Then shp.Delete
    Next shp

End Sub
```

And

```
Sub criarcaixastexto(strName As String)

    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Dim box As Shape

    Set wsActive = Worksheets(2)
    Set box = wsActive.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 20, 20, 100, 50)

    box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Worksheets(1).Range(strName).Value
    box.Name = strName

End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$1", "$A$2", "$A$3"
            removercaixas (Target.Address)
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    If Len(Target) > 1 Then criarcaixastexto (Target.Address)
End Sub
```

Textboxes are created in worksheet 2 all on top of each other. They are deleted appropriately. No textbox is created when the value entered in $A$1:$A$3 has a length of 1 or less. Not sure what the logic is there, but if you want single digit values to create a textbox just change the `Len(Target) > 1` to `Len(Target) > 0`.

Comment: I tried your code with this but it dind't work. I get the following error: Run-time 1004. Method Range of objet Worksheet failed.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

For i = 1 To 3
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A" & CStr(i))) Is Nothing Then
            removercaixas (Target.Address)
        If Len(Target.Address) > 1 Then criarcaixastexto (Target.Address)
        End If
Next

End Sub`

Comment: There are two additional changes to your code: the 'len' and 'intersect' arguments. Are you sure those aren't the culprits? I'm honestly confused about what that part of the code is doing.

Comment: Did this compile? None of my changes seem to be causing the 1004. I've fixed 2 compile errors already, and getting a 1004 on the `box.TextFrame` line due to `i` being out of scope and not defined in the sub. Can you fix all of these issues and then let me know whether my changes fix your initial problem?

Comment: Making the changes you suggest doesn't delete the old version of the textboxes when I update the values in worksheet1

Comment: So you tested this code? sorry, nothing happens in my excel with that code. I kept my code and changed the change event to:
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Call removercaixas
Call criarcaixastexto

End Sub`
it works like I want but will be triggered by any change in any cell of that page. I want it "lighter". What I want if closer to what you suggest. I want the texboxes to update when I change something in the correpondent cell, but it doesn't do that. if I delete cell A1 I want textbox A1 to be deleted, If I write something in A2, I want that texbox to be updated

Comment: That's what the `Select Case` statement does. Just move the `Len` test into the Case statement after the `removercaixas` call if you only want to do anything when a specific cell is affected. Not that any of this matters, because I saw your question history and @Sorceri's comment about `TopLeftCell.Address` will work once the textbox positioning is fixed.

Comment: It won't be...after working out this problem I want the texboxes to be side by side, and the position in the page will have to change according to a choice I will make in a dropdown list in column B.
You said you tested this code, but when I do that nothing is created.

Comment: What value did to put in the cell? Is it more than a length of 1?

Comment: Hm, mine works great. No errors are thrown? If you want to outline your steps I can see if there is something out of place, but the code creates textboxes when new values are entered, and deletes the textbox when the value is removed.

Comment: Ah I bet I know what you are missing: If you don't have the arguments in the procedures then nothing will happen and no error is thrown. Make sure the following is verbatim: `Sub removercaixas(strName As String)` and `Sub criarcaixastexto(strName As String)`

Comment: No, that I have because I copied your exact code. I notice your event change is in workbook and not worksheet. I tried the code to put the code in the Workbook and in the Worksheet(1) but neither one worked, could the problem be there?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry for the inconsistency. I just tested it 30 minutes ago again and copied the workbook change into the worksheet change event and it still worked fine. Have you put a breakpoint on the change event and stepped through? Does it seem to follow the correct paths? Is your `Target.Address` outputting absolute references? Let me know which parts are executing and which are getting missed.

Comment: I copied it in to the workbook and now it's working perfectly. Thank you so much for the help and patience.